# Controls for YoutubeVideoPlayer in JS

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, android-youtube-api

I am using the YoutubeVideoPlayer to play videos in ionic. I was able to get the video to play but I want to make it so the user can not search through the video among other things. Is there a way to get any of these function to work?

Comment: You can do this utilizing the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls)

Comment: I am going to assume I can not use the CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer that is out ther?